# How to optimise lengthly MySQL query with lots of unions

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have this query which I need help with.  So there is a table called `insertjobticket` with column called `DEL` which is a long character field which can have multiple dates in it.  I need to create an output table which contains one row for each time there is a date in the `DEL` field for a certain range of dates.

The reason I can't just do a more simple `select ... where ... DEL like "%my_date%"` is that the `DEL` column can contain multiple dates, and if so, I need to return multiple rows to the output set, one row for each date that appears in the `DEL` column.

The solution I came up with that works, but is very slow looks like this:

```
create temporary table jobtrack.ship_helpert3 as 
select * from 
(
    (
    select  
        date_format(now() - interval 3 day, '%m/%d/%Y') as `Ship_Date`,
        more_columns 
    from   
        jobticket.insertjobticket 
    where         
        DEL like concat('%',date_format(now() - interval 3 day, '%m/%d/%Y'),'%')
    ) union (
    select  
        date_format(now() + interval 2 day, '%m/%d/%Y') as `Ship_Date`,
        more_columns 
    from   
        jobticket.insertjobticket 
    where         
        DEL like concat('%',date_format(now() + interval 2 day, '%m/%d/%Y'),'%')
    ) union (
    select  
        date_format(now() + interval 1 day, '%m/%d/%Y') as `Ship_Date`, 
        more_columns 
    from   
        jobticket.insertjobticket 
    where         
        DEL like concat('%',date_format(now() + interval 1 day, '%m/%d/%Y'),'%')
    ) union ...
) t;
```

Each `select` query checks if there are any rows with a certain date string (`date_format(now() + interval @x day, '%m/%d/%Y')`) in the `DEL` field.  The query is built programmatically and can get very long, as I would like to be able to make the query check for many many dates.

The `insertjobticket` table contains 40K rows and is growing, so the query above takes way too long to complete.  I understand why it takes so long, because every `union` effectively has to make its own sub-query that scans the whole table again and again for each date.  I just don't know how to make this work more efficiently.

Does anyone know how to speed up this query?

Thanks for the help and let me know if we need more clarification.

Comment: Honestly, there is just one solution: Create a new table that contains one date per row instead of having it all in one column `DEL`. If you cannot change your application, do it with a trigger and update your new table whenever you update your column. Anything else you do will just be patchwork (and basically mean creating this new table every time you run that query).

Comment: Yes. Normalise your schema. Or don't bother using an RDBMS.

Comment: I totally understand this suggestion and thanks for that.  A lot of times we need to work on a client's request working in the context of existing infrastructure.  Definitely not ideal the way it is.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind You mean you cannot use a new table? Ok, I will write you a workaround then.

Comment: @Solarflare well what I am doing in my query is creating a new table, as you can see the query creates a temporary table.  The results displayed to the user is actually a query of this temp table.  So i mean I could create this table as permanent and update it with triggers, but I have been trying to stay away from the use of triggers in general.  So for now the query works but is just slow.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind I meant the table to normalize/split up the `DEL` column. Your temporary table is fine and will not have any effect on the underlying query (you just can add `engine=memory` to save some 100ms creation time in case the server does not have this setting in the configuration). I wrote you a workaround that should speed up your query, try it out. I don't think you can get any faster than this without actual normalization (because relational databases work best with relational data). If it is still too slow for your client, try the trigger approach (or adapt the application).

Answer (score 1):

As already stretched in the comments, the only correct solution would be to normalize your data, that means to create a new table with one delivery date and the primary key of `insertjobticket` per row, and let the application use this table directly instead of the column `del`, or at least indirectly by a trigger that updates this table everytime the column `DEL` is updated.

Since you cannot do that, the following workaround should improve your query:

```
select 
  del_dates.Ship_Date, 
  othercolumns 
from insertjobticket
join (
    select concat(date_format(now() + interval 2 day, '%m/%d/%Y')) 
           collate utf8_general_ci as Ship_Date 
    union select concat(date_format(now() + interval 1 day, '%m/%d/%Y')) 
    union select concat(date_format(now() + interval -15 day, '%m/%d/%Y')) 
    ...  
) del_dates
on insertjobticket.del like concat('%', del_dates.Ship_Date, '%');
```

(Change the collation to the one you use in your table or leave it away to see which one, if any, you need).

This will basically do the required normalization step (for the requested dates) every time you execute the query, and will not be able to use indexes. Just make sure your `explain` output shows `using join buffer` for the derived table, not for `insertjobticket`, otherwise replace `join` with a `straight_join`.

For 40k rows, this might not be a big a problem, and there is no other way around it anyway, except real normalization. Keep in mind that your query will slow down linearly with the amount of rows (400k rows will take about 10 times the time as 40k), an effect indexes would prevent. So if it is too slow now (or sometimes in the future), you eventually have to normalize (or, as a workaround to the problems created by this workaround, add a column to mark old entries and exclude them in your join condition).

Btw, since you generate your code programmatically, it shouldn't be a problem to create the list of dates, otherwise you can use another subquery to generate a list of general dates and just select the ones in a specific range.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks for the work-around query, I will give it a try to see if it speeds things up a bit.  I understand what you're saying about the "right" way to do it, with the DEL column in its own table.  Using a date field instead of varchar.  But I don't quite know what you are referring to towards the bottom about indexes.  How would I use indexes to speed up a query?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Indexes are an important part of databases, and explaining them goes way beyond the scope of a comment. You should really read up on it. In short: image how you would look up your phone number in a phone book by your nickname ("date"). You don't read it from start to end - since it's ordered, you can find the result a lot faster (and almost independent of the total number of entries). But if you write two nicknames, e.g. your wife and children ("2nd, 3rd, 4th delivery date") next to each other, it will be hard to find their phone number. That's basically your database design.

Comment: Thanks, its a nice explanation even in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In using a database, you must consider the eventual uses of the stored data.

In this case, you needed to parse `DEL` as you were about to store it, and build another table of pairs of dates (buried in DEL) and ids (of insertjobticket).

Trying to do the parsing after the fact is much slower and leads to scaling problems.